# Setting up django-allauth, receive error: Index column size too large

Tags: python, mysql, django, mariadb, django-allauth

I am attempting to run `./manage.py migrate` when installing django-allauth, which always fails with this error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1709, 'Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.')`

I am using MariaDB 10.1.19 and in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file, I have added the following lines to increase the available index size:

```
[server]
innodb-large-prefix = ON
```

However, the error still occurs.

Later documentation that I have read concerning django-allauth states that this error has been resolved, but I am still experiencing it.

How do I ensure that this configuration directive in the configuration is actually being read and used?

How do I fix this index sizing error?

Thanks!

[Update]:
I added the following to the conf file:

```
[server]
innodb_file_format = BARRACUDA
innodb-large-prefix = ON

[table]
ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC
```

Still receiving the error, however...

[Update 2]
The config file now looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_strict_mode = ON
innodb_file_format = BARRACUDA
innodb-large-prefix = ON
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 702545920
innodb_file_format_max = BARRACUDA
innodb_log_file_size = 50331648
```

These all work, i.e., are listed when I search for the server variables.

I have tried to add:

```
[client]
innodb_default_row_format = dynamic
```

However, that doesn't work. Nor, does it work if I add it under [mysqld]

Answer (score 0):

Instructions (not needed for 5.7.7 and later)

Get MySQL 5.6.3 / 5.5.14 (or later) and...

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
logout & login (to get the global values);
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Then maybe you can index (255) utf8mb4 without having to shrink to 191 because of the 767 limit.

The server section is called `[mysqld]` in MySQL; is it different in MariaDB?

Comment: Please see "Update 2", above. Also, for system reasons, I am required to use MariaDB - switching to MySQL is not an options.

Comment: 10.2.2-MariaDB has those settings already in effect.  I have not found out what version incorporated the code.

Comment: Do you already have the table created?  If so, do the `ALTER`.  If not, add `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` to the `CREATE TABLE`.  Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: 10.0.28 does not have the 5.7.7 settings; 10.2.2 does.

Comment: The error occurs because the "django-allauth" package I am installing does not, I think, take into account the INNODB engine (i.e., assumes MyISAM).

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 is currently hosed on Ubuntu 16.04, because of package incompatibilities, and I am too lazy to install from source.  :-)

Comment: Shrink the 255 to 191.  Or Change the character set.